# React-Native ListView: Dynamic set the contentOffset, The effect is delayed

Tags: listview, react-native

In a screen,I have two ListViews, the leftListView and the rightListView, Set the contentOffset of the leftListView when I slide the rightListView,To keeping the contentOffset at the same level. but the effect of the leftListView is very delay!

you can run my demo to experience the effect

github:[github link](https://github.com/wangchenguang1/GirdShow-React-Native#girdshow-react-native)

```js
 onScroll(){
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      var rightList = this.refs[RIGHT_LISTVIEW];
      var leftList = this.refs[LEFT_LISTVIEW];
      var y1 = leftList.scrollProperties.offset;
      rightList.setNativeProps({
        contentOffset : {x: 0, y: y1}
      });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick look of your repository, it looks like your application is iOS only. If this is the case, you might want to try tweaking the `scrollEventThrottle` prop of your leftmost ListView.

The [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#content) documentation says this of `onScroll`.

> **onScroll function**
>
> Fires at most once per frame during scrolling. The frequency of the events can be controlled using the scrollEventThrottle prop

And this of `scrollEventThrottle`:

> **scrollEventThrottle number**
>
> This controls how often the scroll event will be fired while scrolling (in events per seconds). A higher number yields better accuracy for code that is tracking the scroll position, but can lead to scroll performance problems due to the volume of information being send over the bridge. The default value is zero, which means the scroll event will be sent only once each time the view is scrolled.

The `ScrollView` properties can be passed directly to `ListView`, which inherits from `ScrollView`.

A good number to try to might be `scrollEventThrottle={16}`, which is approximately 60fps. This might or might not yield the effect you want.

Another optimization you might try is to use `Animated.event` to bind the value of  your rightmost `ListView`'s `contentOffset.y` to the contentOffset value of the leftmost one, perhaps offloading some of the heavy lifting to the native execution side, instead of marshalling the events back and forth between JavaScript and native code. That might be a bit complicated to implement though, but check out the [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#content) docs on how to get started on that.